# How to Develop WebAPI to be used in Android App by using existing Asp.net C# project functions

Tags: android, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013

My company is using a portal and is working to develop android app of same.How I can develop WebAPI of  all existing functions and events so that it can be used in Android Application.

I am using below technology.

1-Sharepoint 2007,Visual studio 2008,ASP.NET

2-In my current project Asp.Net user control is used and deployed on sharepoint WebApplication.

Answer (score 0):

WepAPI is not possible with Visual studio 2008.
As I am using Sharepoint 2007,I have created Web Service and exposed all current functions and then hosted it on Sharepoint.Below posts helped me
https://malikhan.wordpress.com/2009/08/07/creating-custom-webservice-in-sharepoint-2007/
http://adrianandroid.blogspot.in/2012/05/access-c-net-web-service-in.html
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396